# Need help handling dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict of word with value 0, I added +1 to the value of the words that I want.
How can I print the dict with only the word that contain value more than 0, and print it in alpha bet order. (In Python)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
d = {"a": 0, "c": 2, "b":1}
for k in sorted(d.keys()):
    if d[k] > 0:
        print(k, d[k])
```

This produces:

```
b 1
c 2
```

Comment: You will need to throw in a `sorted()` somewhere to ensure it is printed in alphabetical order as dicts have no guaranteed order (ignoring Py3.6)

Comment: @AChampion Oh good point, I hadn't read the question carefully enough.

Comment: @AChampion Ok, I updated my answer.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks